# entity framework returns entity without relations after inserting record

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am working on a project and I use the Entity Framework.

My project is based on a repository pattern, so I wrote a generic base class.

My code is like this:

```
public T Add(T entity)
{
    Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    Context.SaveChanges();
    _context = new SafranEntities();

    return entity;
}
```

I want to use the entity for listing after inserting, but this code returns an entity without its relations.

Does anybody know how to achieve this? Thank you.

My entity like this:

```
public partial class NoteInfo
{
    public int NoteID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MemberID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string NoteTopic { get; set; }
    public string NoteText { get; set; }

    public virtual Membership Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectInfo ProjectInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more explicit on what you mean by "without relations".

Comment: How did you realize as it is returning without reference.If the record has reference records. Then it will defenetely return with reference

Comment: Sure. For example a customer entity has relation with city parameter which means where he lives. When I want to access name of the city I must use "CityParameter" relation like "customer.CityParameter.Name". But It returns CityParameter relation null.

Comment: Have you heard of eager loading? Maybe you should try turning that on.

Comment: @NithilaShanmugananthan If I list the customer again  from DB the relations comes with no problem. But entity relations returns null.

Comment: @Oluwafemi yeah but we use singleton pattern and I don't want to change backbone of the repository base.

Comment: You might as well write a further join query to get all related table records.

Comment: @Oluwafemi I think about to write a code which I also using in get item by Id 'Context.Set<T>().Find(id);' but I can't take value of the generic entity Id.

Comment: But you can get the id after returning it and then you can call a new generic method that has this function `Context.Set<T>().Find(id);`

Comment: @Oluwafemi I also use it when getting item by Id. But I use generic class and we can't access like "T.Id" or something. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be that you haven't specified virtual keyword on your Entity.
So, for example, if you have an entity like this

```
public class A{
   public B ReferenceToB {get;set;}
}
```

And then you will do something like :

```
var aObj = new A();
var bObj = new B();
a.ReferenceToB = bObj()
Context.Set<T>().Add(aObj);
```

The reference would be saved in the Database, but when you will try to get the aObj back from the Database the reference would be null.

To fix this, make sure you have all your navigation properties marked **virtual**:

```
public class A{
   public virtual B ReferenceToB {get;set;}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

After understanding what OP really want's I could suggest such changes:

1. Create some interface IEntity and implement it by your classes.
2. Use "where" on generic method, restricting entities by interface IEntity

   `public interface IEntity {
       Guid Id {get;set;}
    }
    public static T Add(T entity) where T:class, IEntity {
       Context.Set().Add(entity);
       Context.SaveChanges();
       return Context.Set().Find(entity.Id);
    }`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you exactly mean but also I generated classes with Entity Framework auto code generate. So there shouldn't be any problem about virtual references. Also If I list the entity again from DB the relations comes with no problem.

Comment: Well, I was referring to CodeFirst approach, because I usually was getting references to other object null, when I was missing the virtual keyword. To make it clearer, could you please post some short code of your classes?

Comment: Ok. So Membership is null, after you saved the entity?

Comment: Yes, all of the relations. Actually It is not just about the NoteInfo table. I have problem all of tables and all of their relations.

Comment: @Burcay Ok, I've created a **[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ozynZC)** to repro the case, but it's working! I can see some Guid in my console. Could you please alter the sample to reproduce your case?

Comment: Very thankful for your advices but there should be simple another way. Have you any idea about access the Id of the entity? So I can use `Context.Set<T>().Find(id)` and then return the entity?

Comment: @Burcay Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean... Obviously you can get the entity by Id using Find(Id), but I don't understand the question/problem... What I've tried to reproduce works fine. Unless you can provide some example of **NON** working code it's really complicated to help you...

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't explain clearly I am new at stackoverflow :). I mean what If I want to call Find(Id ) method in Add method? So in add method I can recall the entity from database after then return the entity from add method? But for this I need Id of the entity. So how can I access the Id like `entity.Id` or something its generic.

Comment: @Burcay If I understand you correctly, I've updated my answer with code. You can also check the [**Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VjjrKQ). Anyway, what you are doing seems strange, becase the relation is NORMALLY not lost after save, so you are adding a workaround instead of searching for the problem.

Comment: I think we can not solve this with this way. How can I contact you?

Answer (score 0):

You should have used lazy loading and checked with breakpoint and saying it is not coming with relations. If thats the case you can refresh it and check.

Comment: No it is just a basic creating a context from model then use it with its functions like `Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);` also I share this in the question. But after that function framework assigns entity a primary ID but with null relations.